# Ideals of orders in number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a number field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an order of $K$ and $A$ a *proper* ideal of $\mathcal{O}$, by which I mean that $\mathcal{O} = \{\alpha \in K : \alpha A \subseteq A\}$.

**Question:**

> Does there exist an *invertible* ideal $I$ of $\mathcal{O}$, such that
>   $I\subseteq A$ and $I\mathcal{O}_K = A\mathcal{O}_K$?

The answer is **yes** for quadratic fields $K$, since then every proper ideal of every order is invertible. Here is an example in degree 3 that motivated this question for me.

**Example:**

> Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ with $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ and consider the order
>
> $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}+2\mathcal{O}_K=\langle 1,2\sqrt[3]{2},2\sqrt[3]{2}^2\rangle_\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> By Example 3.5 of the document
>
> http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/conductor.pdf
>
> on Keith Conrad's webpage, the $\mathbb{Z}$-module
>
> $A = \langle 8, 2\sqrt[3]{2}, 2\sqrt[3]{2}^2 \rangle_\mathbb{Z}$
>
> is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}$ that is proper and not invertible. Moreover,
>
> $A\mathcal{O}_K = \langle 8, 2\sqrt[3]{2}, 2\sqrt[3]{2}^2  \rangle_\mathbb{Z} \langle 1,\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}^2 \rangle_\mathbb{Z} = \langle 4, 2\sqrt[3]{2}, 2\sqrt[3]{2}^2 \rangle_\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> The ideal $I=2\sqrt[3]{2}\mathcal{O}\subseteq A$ is invertible, since it is principal, and moreover
>
> $I\mathcal{O}_K = 2\sqrt[3]{2}\mathcal{O}_K = \langle 4, 2\sqrt[3]{2}, 2\sqrt[3]{2}^2 \rangle_\mathbb{Z} = A\mathcal{O}_K$.

I wouldn't expect a *principal* ideal $I$ with the required properties to exist in general, but maybe *invertible* is good enough?